# Using VLookup in Excel VBA for multiple worksheets

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

We are trying to make a macro that takes a value from column (c) and searches for a value on a separate workbook then pulls two pieces of information from one row and two separate columns. The rest of the code is just turning a word red or green depending on if there is information in the column.

The VLookup function that we are using turns red when we paste it into the excel vba, what are we doing wrong and is there a simple way to fix this. The code is below,

```
Sub MMRFValidation()

Dim c As Range
Dim finder As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each c In Range("C:C")
    If c.Value = "" Then
        c.Offset(, -2).Font.Color = vbRed
        c.Offset(, 11).Value = "Need to contact vendor"
        c.Offset(, 12).Value = "Need to contact vendor"
    Else
        Set finder = Range("C:C").Find(what:=Workbook("U100 Material Information.xlsx").Worksheet("Sheet1").Range("A:A"), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

        leadtime = finder.Offset(, 13).Value
        price = finder.Offset(, 15).Value


        If price = "0.01" And leadtime = "21" Then
            c.Offset(, -2).Font.ColorIndex = 7
            c.Offset(, 11).Value = finder.Offset(, 13).Value
            c.Offset(, 11).Value = finder.Offset(, 15).Value
        Else
            c.Offset(, -2).Font.Color = vbGreen
            c.Offset(, 11).Value = finder.Offset(, 13).Value
            c.Offset(, 11).Value = finder.Offset(, 15).Value
        End If

    End If
Next c
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: First of all, you declared `leadtime As Range` but then you are trying to use a formula (String)?

Comment: `vbPurple` isn't a thing either.

Comment: We changed vbpurple to color index of 7 and we changed leadtime as well as price to strings. We have been running the code for a while and it still hasn't finished

Comment: There's no way that code can run if you changed `leadtime` to a `String`  - `leadtime.Value` would throw an error. Can you [edit] your question with the revised code?

Comment: I may be misreading this but It looks like your lookup range is R1:R1048576 but you are looking for the 13th and 15 columns in that single column range

Comment: I have edited the code

Comment: You are a long ways off from having a running code until you figure out the difference between strings, formulas and ranges.  VLOOKUP is not a string, it is a formula.  It will not return a range.  `Range.Find` will help you find a range.  Then you need to think about efficiency, you are going through 1048576 rows in column C and searching 2 x 1048576 rows in the other file.  Look at finding the last row or `UsedRange`.

Comment: @DarrellH Can you provide an example of Range.find

Comment: This is the Microsoft definition https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Find.  You can also search for examples.  Note the case where nothing is found.

Comment: @DarrellH I have no idea how to use the range.find and we are trying to use the Vlookup function as its the most useful for our case. Without the vba code, the Vlookup function does the job perfectly but we want to place it into a macro where it can do this automatically

Comment: @datatoo yes we are searching that many rows and we only need items from column 13 and 15

Comment: How many rows have values in column 13  or 15 on the Information.xlsx ? How many rows have values in Col C on the worksheet you are coloring ?